# HADR_THROTTLE_LOG_RATE_SEND_RECV_QUEUE_SIZE wait type

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

While uploading (bulk insert via BCP) a large amounts of data to Azure SQL Database I observe a long HADR_THROTTLE_LOG_RATE_SEND_RECV_QUEUE_SIZE waits.

```
select session_id, 
    start_time, 
    s1.text as sql_text,
    wait_type,
    last_wait_type,
    open_transaction_count,
    total_elapsed_time,
    reads,
    writes,
    logical_reads,
    row_count,
    database_id
from sys.dm_exec_requests r
    cross apply sys.dm_exec_sql_text(r.sql_handle) s1
```

Does anybody have an idea what it can be related to? I can't find any information about this wait type on the Internet.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Can  you share what "long" waits are?  Your ability to replicate log records to your other replicas is often the gating resource in bulk loads.

Comment: What tier is the Azure database? Do you have any other replicas attached to it?

Comment: It's PRS6 tier. There are no replicas attached to it.
All such waits observed while insert bulk to tables. There are 10000 rows batches and 5 threads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are uploading to Azure SQL Database, this is likely to do with how fast they will let you push log records to the replicas you have. You can't configure those or decrease any throttling they're going to do; depending on service tier you're likely just going to have to resign yourself to a certain threshold on speed for bulk data transfer, whether you take this speed hit from their throttling, or changes you make yourself by injecting batching / delays to indirectly reduce log writes per time frame.

In other words, the wait isn't documented, and there's nothing you're going to be able to do about it anyway, except maybe move up to a better service tier. But even that is no guarantee, since I am sure there is throttling across the board, and it might even always be the same regardless of tier.

Comment: Aaron, thanks a lot for the response. Database is on PRS6 tier. I understand that there is a certain threshold on speed for bulk insert, but I don't have any replicas configured yet, so it was a little bit confusing to observe such wait type.

Comment: Azure SQL Database has replicas already configured for you, it’s a key component of their DR.

Answer (score 0):

Try to batching the inserts and keep transactions as short as possible as explained on [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-use-batching-to-improve-performance) documentation. Among the techniques to batch inserts you will find table-valued parameters and SQL bulk copy. SqlBulkCopy is 15-30% faster than table-valued parameters for batches of 1,000 and 10,000 rows. Please read the documentation provided.

Consider also to scale up to Premium tiers during these I/O intensive workloads. Premium tiers are intended for that type of workloads. Once the workload finish scale down the tier.

If Geo-replication is in use, please make sure the secondary replica has the same tier of the primary.

Comment: Alberto, thanks a lot for your recommendations. I used 10000 rows per batch as recommended in this article: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlcat/2010/07/30/loading-data-to-sql-azure-the-fast-way/
Maybe I will try 1000 rows batches and compare performance.
It was already Premium tier - PremiumRS 6. I saw that during uploading DTUs was utilized only by 50%.
And yes, there aren't any replicas configured yet.